# Arithmetic right shift: a paradox?

Tags: computer-arithmetic

So I was asked to perform the simple task of doing a 3-bit arithmetic shift of the number 1101 (-3 in 2's complement notation).

Now this is easy and it goes as 1101 -> 1110 -> 1111 -> 1111. So the final result should be 1111 (-1 in 2's complement notation).

However, I also learned that shifting a number p = 3 positions to the right is the same as dividing that number by 2<sup>p</sup> = 8. Therefore shouldn't my result be 0, since -3 divided by 8 is 0 (with remainder -3).

What am I missing in this apparent paradox?

Comment: Please see [Non-equivalence of arithmetic right shift and division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift#Non-equivalence_of_arithmetic_right_shift_and_division).

Comment: As a hint, what happens when you use this process to divide -1 by 2?

Comment: Arithmetic shift right is not the same as logical shift right

Comment: Interesting question .  Division by 2 by shifting right is more like divide by 2 followed by 'floor' operation. ie., For eg:  -0.5 gets rounded to -1, while +0.5 gets rounded to 0.

Answer (score 12):

Right shifting of a negative two's complement number is indeed equivalent to division as you stated, but *always rounding down* (towards minus infinity). So no paradox here - division of `-1` by `2` gives `-0.5` which is rounded down to the same `-1`.

P.S. The rounding down is also true for positive numbers shifted.

Answer (score 7):

Shifting right is dividing by two and rounding down.

So -3 / 2 = -1.5, rounded down to -2. -2 / 2 = -1, rounded down to -1. -1 / 2 = -0.5, rounded down to -1.